# Intellij 2018.3 default autocomplete disable

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

In my work, I'm using mostly XML files with custom tags.

Also, I configured autocompletion for some tags through Live Templates.

But now, when I am typing, for ex:

`<ob` trying to autocomplete some of my `<object`
 tag),  autocomplete suggest me something like:

```
        xmlns="jar://C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5/plugins/jBPM/lib/jbpm-support.jar!/schemas/jbmn20/Semantic.xsd"
```

Other example:

```
<geronimo-plugin-list xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/plugins-1.1"></geronimo-plugin-list>
```

How can i turn off all basic suggestions in Intellij?
That autocomplete automaticly turnes off when I add
`<?xml>` tag + 1 additional tag, but i want to disable it in all cases.
T.y.

Comment: Do you mean that suggestion is placed instead of Live Template?

Comment: No. I just mean thats my list of suggestions is full of default tags that I want to turn off